# Portability worries because of custom cursor path in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, clickonce, custom-cursor

I am using a custom cursor named `hand2.cur` in my C#-WPF application. I have added the cursor to a folder named `Images` which has all the images that I use in my application. However I've realized that I cannot add relative path to use my custom cursor as:

```
    Cursor newCur = new Cursor("Images\\hand2.cur");
    window.Cursor = newCur;
```

So I used this:

```
    string absolute = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath("hand2.cur");
    Cursor newCur = new Cursor(absolute);
    window.Cursor = newCur;
```

This tries to find the `hand2.cur` file in the `\bin\Release` folder. So I added the file there and I got it working.

But the problem is, if I `Publish` this application and use it on a different computer, it does not work. Now the problem is with the cursor file path, because if I deploy it after commenting those 3 lines, it works correctly. So what do I do to rectify this problem?

I am using other images from the `Image` folder in my XAML code and they seem to port fine. But then again my knowledge of WPF is limited so if anyone has any ideas, that would help.

EDIT: I have added my Images folder to the project. I have also set the Build Action of the cursor file `hand2.cur` to `Embedded Resource`. However when I use the following two lines, I get an `XAMLParseException`.

```
    System.Windows.Resources.StreamResourceInfo info = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Slideshow;component/Images/hand2.cur"));
        window.Cursor = new System.Windows.Input.Cursor(info.Stream);
```

The `Inner Exception` field when I view the details of the error reads: `{"Cannot locate resource 'images/hand2.cur'."}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make the cursor a resource in your app/assembly and then use [GetResourceStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms596994%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with the [pack Uri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx) to the resources location. Pass the Stream of the StreamResourceInfo to the ctor of the Cursor. e.g.

```
var info = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/hand2.cur"));
var cursor = new Cursor(info.Stream);
```

Comment: Hi @AndrewS Please check the edit I made and let me know what I did wrong.

Comment: Ok I changed my response. The file should have been marked as Resource - not embedded resource which was incorrect. Also the pack notation you were using would be if this was in a referenced assembly - i.e. not in the main application assembly. The snippet I included would work in the application's assembly.

Answer (score 0):

I've got this working after I added the cursor file `hand2.cur` to my `Resource1.resx` resource file. Then I used the following statement in my code:

```
window.Cursor = new Cursor(new System.IO.MemoryStream(MyNameSpace.Resource1.hand2));
```